# Lie group representatiom - quasi-equivalent representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $T$ and $U$ be unitary representations of a conected simply conected nilpotent Lie group, such that all irreducible subrepresentations of $T$ and $U$ are the same.

If $T$ and $U$ are finite, then they are quasi-equivalent. Is it also true if they are infinite?